# Fourier Transform Help

Tags: plotting, numerics

I'm trying to do a Fourier Transform of the following [Data](http://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/greenwch/spot_num.txt), but I'm completely stuck.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
data = Drop[data, 1];
dat = data /. {x_, y_, z_, w_} -> {x + y/12., 10 z};
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[dat]], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 40}}]
```

I don't understand why it keeps displaying this weird plot
[image]

Anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong? I'm just learning this Fourier thing so I'm real lost.

Comment: Try `ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[dat]], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 350}}]` [Result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E4mQU.png)

Answer (score 5):

`Fourier` does not accept a list of {time, sample} pairs - if you give it a 2D list it will do a 2D transform. Therefore you need to use `Fourier` on just the list of samples. To get the correct frequency scale on the plot you can use [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DataRange.html).

```
data = Import["http://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/greenwch/spot_num.txt", "Table"];

dat = Rest[data] /. {x_, y_, z_, _} :> {x + y/12., 10 z};

n = Length[dat];
t = dat[[2, 1]] - dat[[1, 1]];
fourierdata = Abs @ Fourier[dat[[All, 2]]];

ListLinePlot[fourierdata[[;; 1 + n/2]],
 DataRange -> {0, 1/(2 t)},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 10000}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I can't figure out how I was able to avoid seeing DateRange in the docs.